# Is it possible to position Highcharts dataLabels depending on the value?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to display a bar chart, with 2 bars overlaying each other, and a dataLabels at the right of them, displaying the exact value.

The problem here is that when the value is above 80%, the label is overflowing from the chart into the frame, going over some other text, and making them both unreadable.

Here are my `plotOptions` :

```
plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                groupPadding: 0.5,
                pointWidth : 30,
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    y:-5,
                    color:"black",
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "12px"
                    },
                    formatter: function(){
                        if(this.y > 80)
                        {
                            this.series.chart.options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.x -= 20;
                        }
                        if(this.series.name == "Tests OK")
                            return "Tests OK : <strong>"+Math.round(this.y*10)/10+"%</strong>";
                        else
                            return "<br/>Tests Executed : <strong>"+Math.round(this.y*10)/10+"%</strong>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I thought i could edit the chart options on the go, using `this.series.chart.options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.x -= 20;`, but this doesn't work.

Surely I'm not the first one who has encountered a problem like that. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible to do that from within the `formatter`.

But you could set them after the chart is rendered (loaded). Try something like this

```
$.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
    if(point.y > 100) {
        point.dataLabel.attr({x:20});
    }
});
```

in the `load callback` (or if you need it in the `redraw callback`).

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9m6wu/345/).

Comment: Thanks it worked after some arrangements. My charts do not load data at building time, because there are 3 massive charts on the page. Instead, they do so individually after the page is fully loaded. This code must be used after the data is inserted in the graph, and it is redrawn.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I ended up with. The setTimeout is necessary or the dataLabel property doesn't exist on the point:

```
formatter: function () {
    var point = this.point;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (point.s < 0) {
            point.dataLabel.attr({
                y: point.plotY + 20
            });
        }
    });
    //this.series.options.dataLabels.y = -6;
    var sty = this.point.s < 0 ? 'color:#d00' : 'color:#090;' //other style has no effect:(
    return '<span style="' + sty + '">' + Math.abs(this.point.s) + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: This works great. Worth noting that the formatter function should exist within {plotOptions:dataLabels}

Answer (score 4):

Although Bhesh's answer solves the problem for x/y positioning, Highcharts ignores any changes to the style property of dataLabels ([see the problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/9m6wu/135/)). However, you can override the styles of an individual point by passing it through the data object:

```
series: [{ data: [29.9, 106, { y: 135, dataLabels: { style: { fontSize: 20 } } }]
```

[example from Highcharts docs](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/datalabels/)

I was able to get dynamic styles by iterating over my data before passing the whole object to Highcharts to render.

Comment: I used this technique and it worked great. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure some of this out myself... it looks like instead of

```
this.series.chart.options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.x -= 20;
```

could you use...

```
this.series.options.dataLabels.x = -20;
```

... at this point I'm trying to understand if I'm able to discern the location of a dataLabel so that I can reposition it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work either. By logging `this.series` into the formatter, i can see that the line is taken into account, because the `dataLabels.x` is in fact equal to `-20`, but no change in the display...